# Django DetailView - get all objects?

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a subclass of `DetailView` to show details on a single object (obv). 
I also have a subclass of `ListView` which provides the homepage (with some info on all projects)

But now I want to include a sidebar in my base template so that all pages will have links to each view provided by `DetailView`.

How can I do this in a way such that I can access all objects in the template provided by `DetailView` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourDetailView(DetailView):
    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(YourDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_objects'] = YourModel.objects.all()

        return context
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data

Answer (score 0):

A couple of DRY methods:

1. Have all your DetailViews inherit from a base DetailView that uses `get_context_data` to retrieve the objects and adds them to the context
2. Write a custom [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) and use it in your base template